# how to change "npm scripts" directory

Tags: npm, npm-install, npm-scripts

```json
"scripts": {
   ...
   ...
   "puppeteer": "cd test/UI-tests/src && set BROWSER=chrome && mocha test.js"
}
```

I want to wrap all the commands in "puppeteer", so once I type `npm run puppeteer`, it can set the browser and run the `test.js` file. 
The way I write it does not work.

Comment: You can't so far.

Comment: I can only add commands which are in node_modules/.bin folder?